# Is it possible to add all IHostedService classes with a loop (ASP.NET Core 6)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, ihostedservice

Is it possible to add all `IHostedService` implemented classes in a loop without adding them individually in ASP.NET Core 6?

Let's say we have this two implementations:

```
public class FirstImplementationOfHostedService : IHostedService 
{
    // ...
}

public class SecondImplementationOfHostedService : IHostedService 
{
    // ...
}
```

The default way in `Program.cs` to add them is:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<FirstImplementationOfHostedService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SecondImplementationOfHostedService>();
```

But, what about having a hundred implementations?

There has to be a better way to add (at runtime) the one hundred implementations in `Program.cs` without explicitly spelling out all their names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an nuget package like [this](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) or you can create an extension method and get all references of services with reflection:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
   public static void RegisterAllTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services, 
   Assembly[] assemblies,
    ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
   {
      var typesFromAssemblies = assemblies.SelectMany(a => 
       a.DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))));
      foreach (var type in typesFromAssemblies)
        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(T), type, lifetime));
   }
 }
```

and than call it at startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ....

    services.RegisterAllTypes<IInvoicingService>(new[] { typeof(Startup).Assembly });
}
```

But be careful , you are registering services in a collection. There is a long version of answer [here](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-inject-all-instances-of-a-service-interface-64b37b43fdc8). You should check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrutor which does assembly scanning (which it seems like what you want) https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @nzrytmn totally worked. Thank you very much!

I just made a few tweaks in `RegisterAllTypes` to fulfill my own requirements:

```
public static void RegisterAllTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   var assemblies = new[] { Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() };

   var typesFromAssemblies = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a?.DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))));
   
   foreach (var type in typesFromAssemblies)
      services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(T), type, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
}
```

Then in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.RegisterAllTypes<IHostedService>();
```